# Can't pop up complete text

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
    Afterdata = "<div><span><input type=text class=inputtext value="+text+">"+
    "</span>" +
    "<span class=save><input type=button value=Save></span>" +
    "<span class=cancel><input type=button value=Cancel></span></div>"
    $(this).parent().html(Afterdata);
    //$(".inputtext").val(text);
```

What is here is a fragment of my code, the `var text` is the data that is retrieved from the span, say `text = "how you doing"`. Basically what my code is doing is that after I click on the span text field, it transforms into a input text field along with two buttons as shown above, where the text field keeps the text from the span, ("how you doing"). It is supposed to display a input box that is pre-filled with "how you doing" but it only fills with "how" without the following "you doing" part. The weird thing is that the alert function display "how you doing" successfully and commented bottoms line displays "how you doing" as well. However, the weirdest one is that my another function works like a charm:

```
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).parent().html("<span class=sample>"+text+"</span>" +
            "<span><input type=button value=Delete class=delete></span>");
```

which is the same idea. The only difference is that the substituted part in the later one is in span instead of the value of input. see the difference? I have no clue; any help?

Comment: In any case, add escaping, if text contains < > it can brake when moving from attribute value to node text value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html you generate is something like this:

```
<div><span><input type=text class=inputtext value=how you doing></span>...
```

(the rest is not important)

As you can see, the `value` property needs quotes. Also, you should consider the case where the text contains quotes, so those need to be escaped.

**EDIT**: you can do it like this:

```
Afterdata = "<div><span><input type=text class=inputtext value=\"" + text.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + "\">" + "</span>" + "<span class=save><input type=button value=Save></span>" + "<span class=cancel><input type=button value=Cancel></span></div>"
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/UVvSc/1/).

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I dont understand this part. \"" + text.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + "\", could you explain it a little bit? Thank you

Comment: it just [replaces](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) any double quote character in the string `text`, for `&quot;`. this allows you to put the string in the html and not accidentally close the `value` parameter. the first and last parts (where you see this: `\"`) adds double quotes, so the final html looks like this: `<input value="how you doing">` (I omitted some stuff for brevity)

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes to your `value` attribute

Comment: if I add quotes to my value attribute, it is going to display "how you doing" only, what I am doing is that the "how you doing" part needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Ass camberca said, add quotes as escaped: "\"" or use single quote (Apostrophe - ').